# Windows Command Line Group Policy - Using findstr/regex

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, findstr, group-policy

Using Windows Command Line, I am listing out the Administrative Templates Group Policy settings using this command: gpresult /Scope User /v

An example of the output I am receiving is seen down below:

```
Administrative Templates
    ------------------------
        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaverIsSecure
            Value:       49, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut
            Value:       57, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE
            Value:       115, 0, 99, 0, 114, 0, 110, 0, 115, 0, 97, 0, 118, 0, 101, 0, 46, 0, 115, 0, 99, 0, 114, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveActive
            Value:       49, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled
```

I am trying to modify the command to be able to use a findstr type way of listing a specific Administrative Template setting and have been unsuccessful in trying to find the correct syntax. For example, from the list seen above, I am trying to only get back the results of this setting only and nothing else:

```
    GPO: Local Group Policy
        Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut
        Value:       57, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0
        State:       Enabled
```

Any help is much appreciated.